# Sending .wav file to backend

Tags: javascript, wav, recorder

I am currently using RecorderJS and need to send a .wav file to the backend. the API is quite limited in documentation so I am struggling to figure out how to send the .wav file through my axios.post(...).

I am able to download the .wav file with

```
Recorder.download(theblob, 'audio.wav');
```

this downloads a .wav file which I can play through itunes so it is the right format. I now need to figure out how to save this in a variable in order to post it through axios. Also, what should i use for me headers, .. ect?

Looking for any kind of javascript solution to this. I just need to send the exact downloaded file to my backend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The download method stores the file somewhere on your disk. I believe javascript cannot traverse your computer's path and read files for security reasons. I'm not sure if recorder-js offers storing it in a variable "out of the box", so you may want to get that handled first.

For your second part of the question:

This should work for posting it to the back-end:

```
let data = new FormData();

data.append('wavfile', file, file.name);

const config = {
  headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
}
axios.post('/api/recorderfiles', data, config)
```

Comment: yeah, even if I hard code in a file for the second part, I still get the response that no data was sent in. Is there anyway for me to get the first part done? Even if it is super hacky? this is just for a hackathon project. I could be passing in the wrong values to file, and filename. Should they be a path to the file? how does that part work

Comment: No not a path. The file is the file object, so you need a real file stored in the variable "file". You can upload the file manually in a regular html form if that's OK? with an input=file:  <input type="file" name="wavfile">  and then use javascript to sense a change (event.target.files[0]) to retrieve the file.

Comment: Im not sure this would work. Would it be possible for us to direct message / call? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, no availability today. What do you think of this: https://github.com/ijsnow/studiojs/blob/master/recorder/src/index.js <- here you see the stop() method, which you can change. in the callback you can create a file from buffer with this and then send it with axios!

Comment: Okay true. So I could just copy and paste there stop into mine? Im not entirely sure How this would look with axios? It seems like I am sort of already doing that. If you could quickly show me what that would look like i would really appreciate it! currently i have onStop = blobObject => { ...}

Comment: No, edit their "stop". Create a file from the buffer (take a look here; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer)  and then post it with axios.

Comment: I think that would require rearchitecting my current solution quite a bit because of the way I am using the Recorder is a bit differently (it is in react components). Your axios post seems to be working with my current solution, I just need a way to get the data into a file. I tried passing Recorder.download(blobObject.blob, 'audio'); directly into the data field but it just returns undefined. Is there a way for me to specifically save the .wav to my cd and then use it like that?